# turn MYSQL query result to different columns as shown in the description

Tags: mysql

Hey please I need help with a MYSQL query if you could please read on ill include almost everything you need.

Note: I have read multiple answers before I post but i'm not sure if these answers sort my issue.

The Query i'm using:

```
SELECT
   t1.name AS product_name,
   t1.description AS product_description,
   GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) AS category
   FROM cdxc_product_description t1 INNER JOIN
   cdxc_product_to_category t3
   ON t3.product_id = t1.product_id INNER JOIN
   cdxc_category_description t2
  ON t2.category_id = t3.category_id
  GROUP BY t1.name, t1.description;
```

The result I get:

```
product_name  |   product_description |  product_category
-----------------------------------------------------------
 NAME 1       |     Description 1     |     Cat1,Cat2,Cat5

 NAME 2       |     Description 2     |     Cat7,Cat2,Cat1
```

Is there any way I could get a result like this?

```
product_name  |   description |  category | category2 | category3
-----------------------------------------------------------
 NAME 1       | Description 1 | Cat1      |   Cat2    |    Cat5

 NAME 2       | Description 2 | Cat7      |   Cat2    |    Cat1
```

PLEASE NOTE:
I do not want to make sql generate anything dynamically as I know it's not possible, i just want you to point me to the right direction to get the result mentioned done either via a totally different query with a different approach or by just a modification to my query.

Comment: For me it produces the latter behaviour - which is the expected behaviour for group_concat(). No rdbms can create fields dynamically, I do not understand how you would get the first result. Unless you mixed up the expected and actual results in your question.

Comment: If you mixed up the expected and actual results in the question, then it is a duplicate question...

Comment: i have updated the question because i saw your comment, thank you for trying to help

Comment: and please if it's a duplicate question please include the link so i can use it

Comment: I still don't get your question. Group_concat() produces the output as described under "Is there any way I could get a result like this?"

Comment: ok let me explain it easily,  forget about group_concat() please, what would you do to get the result i am aiming for (in the question)

Comment: You still don't get it! Group_concat produces the result that you describe in your question.

Comment: @Shadow i get the following result  Cat1,Cat2,Cat5 under the category field, while i want to get each one in a separate column (not dynamically as i will set them myself)
I have tried using offset but that didn't work so what do you think i should do?

Comment: OK, this way it is clear now. Which in turn means that the question is a duplicate.